# How to add has_many :through details to a form RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-many

I'm doing what appears to be a common learning app for Ruby on Rails, the recipe app. Specifically, working on recipes and ingredients as a has_many :through relationship.  Through looking at a million examples and questions, I've got my many-to-many relationship setup and my multi-model form working, but I'd like to add an additional field and can't get it working.  Feels like I'm close to understanding how this stuff works.  Here are the quick details:

Models:

```
class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :recipe_ingredients
  has_many :recipes, :through => :recipe_ingredients
end

class RecipeIngredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recipe
  belongs_to :ingredient
end

class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :recipe_ingredients
  has_many :ingredients, :through => :recipe_ingredients
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients, :recipe_ingredients

  def new_recipe_ingredient_attributes=(recipe_ingredient_attributes)
    recipe_ingredient_attributes.each do |attributes|
      recipe_ingredients.build(attributes)
    end
  end

  def existing_recipe_ingredient_attributes=(recipe_ingredient_attributes)
    recipe_ingredients.reject(&:new_record?).each do |recipe_ingredient|
      attributes = recipe_ingredient_attributes[recipe_ingredient.id.to_s]
      if attributes
        recipe_ingredient.attributes = attributes
      else
        recipe_ingredient.delete(recipe_ingredient)
      end
    end
  end

  def save_recipe_ingredients
    recipe_ingredients.each do |recipe_ingredient|
      recipe_ingredient.save(false)
    end
  end
end
```

Controller:

```
def create
   @recipe = Recipe.new(params[:recipe])
   if @recipe.save
         redirect_to :action => 'show', :id => @recipe
         flash[:notice] = "Your record has been saved."
   else
         render :action => 'new'
   end
end

def update
   params[:recipe][:existing_recipe_ingredient_attributes] ||= {}
   @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
   if @recipe.update_attributes(params[:recipe])
      redirect_to :action => 'show', :id => @recipe
      flash[:notice] = "Your changes have been saved."
   else
      render :action => 'edit'
   end
end
```

View:

```
<% form_for(@recipe) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
etc.....
    Ingredients:
    <div id="recipe_ingredients">
      <div class="recipe_ingredient">
      <% new_or_existing = recipe_ingredient.new_record? ? 'new' : 'existing' %>
      <% prefix = "recipe[#{new_or_existing}_recipe_ingredient_attributes][]" %>
      <% fields_for prefix, recipe_ingredient do |ri_form| %>
        <p>
          <%= ri_form.collection_select(:id, Ingredient.find(:all), :id, :name, :include_blank => true) %>
          <%= ri_form.text_field :amount %>
        </p>
      <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit 'Create' %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Sorry for the wall of code, hopefully it makes sense. The thing I can't understand is why the "amount" text field doesn't work.  I've tried a million different ways, but can't get it working. In this case, the error I get is "undefined method `amount' for #"

What key connection am I missing here?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance it appears you should simply replace:

```
      <% fields_for prefix, recipe_ingredient do |ri_form| %>
```

with:

```
      <%= fields_for prefix, recipe_ingredient do |ri_form| %>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a look, but it seems like that made it worse. I now have a compile error.  compile error
/home/jchandler/rails-tests/recipes/app/views/recipes/_recipe_ingredient.html.erb:4: syntax error, unexpected ')'
...cipe_ingredient do |ri_form| ).to_s); @output_buffer.concat ...
                              ^
/home/jchandler/rails-tests/recipes/app/views/recipes/_recipe_ingredient.html.erb:12: syntax error, unexpected kENSURE, expecting ')'
/home/jchandler/rails-tests/recipes/app/views/recipes/_recipe_ingredient.html.erb:14: syntax error, unexpected kEND, expecting ')'

Comment: and what is line 4 of `/views/recipes/_recipe_ingredient.html.erb`.

Comment: Sorry, its the line you suggested the change on.  

<%= fields_for prefix, recipe_ingredient do |ri_form| %>

Comment: Weird. Did you try to put prefix and recipe_ingredient inside brackets?

Comment: Sorry, got moved to a project and haven't gotten back to this.  As it was just for practice, I'll probably just let it go for now.  Thanks for your help anyway.